# Encoding of python3 in terminal and IDE on Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, encoding, terminal, ide

I found many of the solution about encode error while using python3 in IDE, but none of these can solve my problem.

The problem is when I try to read a html file by `with open('xxx.html', 'r') as file`, I always got **UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte xxxx** while I was using IDE like vs code or REPL in sublime text. But while I use terminal in my Mac to run the same code, it works very well.

My development environment is English and I've tried *almost* everything. For example `# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-`or `file.read().decode('utf8')`. But all the methods I found are not worked with my problem.

So my questions are:
1. How to solve these encoding issue while using IDE?
2. Why there's no error while I directly run the same code in terminal?

Thanks.